2004 Durango brake lights
Just bought this Durango and brake lights didn't work, there were fuses missing,I replaced, bulbs look good yet no brake lights
Oh and also bought new brake light switch hooked it to connector yet still no lights.
Any ideas before I start tracing wires ?
